# JDBC Call to Oracle Stored Procedure with parameters of type PL SQL table

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, plsql, database-cursor

I need to make JDBC call to a procedure with parameters of type PL/SQL table.
I am trying with struct object. But I am not doing some thing correct.
I get the error:
ORA-04043: object "scott"."objListStruct" does not exist.

Here is the code snippet:

```
conn = Application.getDBConnection();
CallableStatement cStmt = null;
cStmt= conn.prepareCall("{call package1.procedure1"+"(?)}");
Struct objListStruct = conn.createStruct("objListStruct",
                objNameArr.toArray());
cStmt.setObject(1, objListStruct,Types.STRUCT);
```

The parameter, "?" for this procedure, is  of type:

```
TYPE t_name IS TABLE OF TABLE1.name%TYPE
```

Any insight to make this work is highly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: objNameArr is an arrayList with data ready to go in.

Comment: In one of your comments, you say "Strictly speaking, the type should be TYPE t_name IS TABLE OF TABLE1.name%TYPE INDEX by BINARY_INTEGER".  That conflicts with the type definition you give here.  Which is correct?  Is the type in Oracle defined in SQL or PL/SQL?

Answer (score 2):

```
String[] varStrArr = varArr.toArray(new String[compNameArr.size()]);
OracleCallableStatement cStmt = (OracleCallableStatement) 
conn.prepareCall("BEGIN SCHEMA.PACKAGE.procedure(?);END;");
cStmt.setPlsqlIndexTable(1,varStrArr,varStrArr.length,varStrArr.length,
                        OracleTypes.VARCHAR, 50);
cStmt.execute();
```

The above code works. 
More reference material is available at:
[Binding IN Parameters](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14355/oraint.htm#BABCHCGF)

Comment: Using OracleCallableStatement and calling setPlsqlIndexTable() on that statement are the two things I did to get this working.

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1)  The easiest way is to not pass anything to the procedure.  Create a global temporary table, insert all the data you need, then call the proc, which reads from your temporary table.  Just be careful that you aren't autocommitting your connection.

2)  If you *have* to pass in an array, you'll need to drop down and use the Oracle Array type.  The Oracle array type will bind to the table type.  So something similar (NOTE: code not tested!) to this:

```
Object[] arrayObject = { x, y };

ArrayDescriptor descriptor = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor(
        "MY_SCHEMA.MY_ARRAY_TYPE", conn);
ARRAY myArray = new ARRAY(descriptor, conn, arrayObject);


CallableStatement cs = conn
        .prepareCall("{ call package1.procedure1(?)}");
cs.setArray(1, myArray);
cs.execute();
conn.close();
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try this. I assume MY_SCHEMA is my schema name.

Comment: In your example, it will be t_name.

Comment: Thanks @Nick I am getting closer but still one step away. Strictly speaking, the type should be TYPE t_name IS TABLE OF TABLE1.name%TYPE INDEX by BINARY_INTEGER. If I add INDEX BY to create the type, I am getting error: PL SQL type not allowed. with out INDEX BY clause I am getting run time error: operation not allowed: Ordinal binding and Named binding cannot be combined! -@Kumars

Comment: The error message is: wrong number or types of arguments in call to procedure1

Comment: try {
      conn = Application.getDBConnection();
      ArrayDescriptor compNameArrDesc = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor(
            "TYPE1", conn);
      ArrayDescriptor molWtArrDesc = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor(
            "TYPE2", conn);
      ArrayDescriptor specGRArrDesc = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor(
            "TYPE3", conn);
      ArrayDescriptor BPArrDesc = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor(
            "TYPE4", conn);
    ARRAY ARR1 = new ARRAY(compNameArrDesc, conn, CArr1.toArray());
    ARRAY ARR2 = new ARRAY(molWtArrDesc, conn, CArr2.toArray());

Comment: ARRAY ARR3 = new ARRAY(specGRArrDesc, conn, CArr3.toArray());
    ARRAY ARR4 = new ARRAY(BPArrDesc, conn, CArr4.toArray());
    CallableStatement cStmt = null;
      cStmt= conn.prepareCall("BEGIN package_name.procedure_name"+"(?,?,?,?,?,?);END;");
      cStmt.setArray(1, ARR1);
      cStmt.setArray(2, ARR2);
      cStmt.setArray(3,ARR3);
      cStmt.setArray(4,ARR4 );
      cStmt.setInt(5, Integer.valueOf(pID));
    cStmt.setInt(6, Integer.valueOf(rID));
    boolean result = cStmt.execute();

Comment: return true; 
   } catch (SQLException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
   } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
   }

Comment: Please take a look at the above code snippets. Sorry I could not post it as one snippet with good indentation. -@kumars

Comment: Why are you specifying "TYPE1" as your createDescriptor instead of t_name?

Comment: It should be type1. t_name is a typo. I have types called TYPE1,TYPE2,TYPE3 and TYPE4 defined.  TYPE1 in stored proc is defined as follows:TYPE TYPE1 IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(50) INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER  . But BINARY_INTEGER is available only fo PL SQL Procedures. CreateDescriptor makes an SQL call which does not recognize TYPE1. SO I have TYPE1 defined as : CREATE TYPE TYPE1 as TABLE of VARCHAR2(50). i.e. with out the INDEX BY clause. That satisifies the compiler. But at run time I get wrong type of arguments error.

Comment: I am getting java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-04043: object "SCHEMA"."type" does not exist. I don't have a clue what is happening.

Comment: I thought you said your type was defined as type1?